# About Power and Indent in C

Tags: c

I'm currently studying C. And doing this, I have a question.
As you see, I don't want that white part printed out.
But it keeps showing me that. What's wrong with my code?

Output:

[image: 1]

And this is the output what  want:

[image: 2]

```
#include <stdio.h>

void indent(int);
int tab = 0;
double power(double x, int n) {
    indent(tab);
    double result;
    
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    else if ((n % 2) == 0) {
        printf("power(%lf, %d)\n", x, n);
        ++tab;
        result = power(x * x, n / 2);
    }
    else {
        printf("power(%lf, %d)\n", x, n);
        ++tab;
        result = x * power(x * x, (n - 1) / 2);
    }
    --tab;
    indent(tab);
    printf("power(%lf, %d) = %lf\n", x, n, result);
    return result;
}
```

```
int main() {
    double num1;
    int num2;
    while (1) {
        printf("\n>> ");
        scanf_s("%lf %d", &num1, &num2);
        if (num2 == 0) {
            break;
        }
        printf("%lf ^ %d = %lf", num1, num2, power(num1, num2));
    }
    return 0;
}

void indent(int t)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
        printf("   ");
}
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post text as formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

The extra white space in that line appears because every execution of `power` prints out spaces at the beginning even if it executes the `return 1;` and does not print anything else out. To get rid of that white space, move the first `indent(tab);` to after the line with `return 1;` and change the `else if` after it to just `if`. (It does not need the `else` because the `return` will guarantee control will not flow to this point of the `if` test is true.)

I suspect you do also wish to get rid of the remainder of that line, just the excess white space. If you do wish to get rid of the line entirely, think about an `if` test you can put just after `--tab;` to avoid executing the following code.